# писать в stdout nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, потоки-данных, express

index.js:

```
var sys = require('sys'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec;
...

var result;
child = exec('phantomjs ./phantom/folder/search.js',
    function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        result = stdout;
        console.log(result);
    }
);
```

`stdout` пустой, в файле `search.js` есть переменная которую я хочу в `stdout` передать. не могу разобраться как это сделать?

**UPD**:

```
var result;
child = exec('phantomjs ./phantom/iaai/search.js',
    function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        result = stdout;
        console.log(result) // корректный ответ содержащий stdout
    }
);
console.log(result); // undefined
```

По какой-то причине `stdout` не записывается в result. Как получить доступ к этим данным за пределами `function(error, stdout, stderr) {}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция function(error, stdout, stderr) принимает в параметре stdout то, что помещает в stdout выполняемый ей процесс. Поэтому требуется в search.js что-нибудь вывести в stdout. Например при помощи `console.log('что-то')`

### К обновлению в вопросе

exec - это асинхронная функция, она возвращает результат сразу же. И сразу после этого вы вызываете `console.log(result);` При этом, конечно же, result неопределен, потому что при объявлении вы его не инициализировали, а `function(error, stdout, stderr)` внутри exec еще не выполнилась, она выполнится асинхронно, после завершения запущенного процесса.

Для того, чтобы "все работало" вам надо делать свой код так же асинхронным или использовать [синхронный запуск процесса](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_synchronous_process_creation)

Comment: Ага, спасибо, а еще вопрос: когда пытаюсь вызвать console.log(result); за пределами child получаю undefined. хотя по-идеи он должен содержать stdout. почему так?

Comment: Точнее я не понимаю как получить stdout  за пределами моей функции?

Comment: что значит **за пределами child** и **за пределами моей функции** непонятно. Может чуть дополните вопрос кодом с примерами?

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение